# How to make a JFrame display possible errors?

Tags: java, exception, jframe, jtextarea

Let's say I've got a JFrame and want it to display every exception that has been thrown during runtime in a JTextArea except the ones related to the frame itself. (obviously, because the frame wouldn't open up then). Is this possible?

Comment: You are probably looking for a way to redirect `System.err` and a thread default exception handler...

Answer (score 0):

You can gather the output of the stack trace by using a `StringWriter` and appending the result to your text area as a `String`. Something like this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
    textArea.append(sw.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.  In order to display any information at all about a given exception, it is necessary to *catch* that exception.  You could arrange to catch exceptions that otherwise would go uncaught, and you can arrange to catch exceptions thrown by objects directly under your control, but no object can catch or handle exceptions that are first caught by some other object.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect System.out or System.err to a JTextArea.

See [Message Console](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) for one approach.